# Mockito.any() for <T>

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, mongodb-java, springmockito

I want to mock a method with signature as:

```
public <T> T documentToPojo(Document mongoDoc, Class<T> clazz)
```

I mock it as below:

```
Mockito.when(mongoUtil.documentToPojo(Mockito.any(Document.class), Mockito.any(WorkItemDTO.class)))
```

But I get error as:

The method `documentToPojo(Document, Class<T>)` in the type `MongoUtil` is not applicable for the arguments `(Document, WorkItemDTO)`

Is there any method in Mockito which will help me mock for T?

Comment: Why do you need to mock the second parameter?

Comment: Actually I want to return mock object for this method. I am not mocking second parameter. I am mocking the documentToPojo method

Comment: Sorry, I tried to express, wouldn't this work? `Mockito.when(mongoUtil.documentToPojo(Mockito.any(Document.class), WorkItemDTO.class))` Without the second `any`?

Comment: Just like `Mockito.any(Document.class)` says to accept any `Document`, your second parameter says to accept any `WorkItemDTO`, when you really want to accept any `Class`. As the answer below says, use `Mockito.any(Class.class)`.

Comment: @GáborBakos: Yes, but you need an `eq()` wrapper. If one parameter uses a Mockito matcher, they all must use Mockito matchers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Note that `documentToPojo` takes a *Class* as its second argument. `any(Foo.class)` returns an argument of type `Foo`, not of type `Class<Foo>`, whereas `eq(WorkItemDTO.class)` should return a `Class<WorkItemDTO>` as expected. I'd do it this way:

```
when(mongoUtil.documentToPojo(
    Mockito.any(Document.class),
    Mockito.eq(WorkItemDTO.class))).thenReturn(...);
```

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using Java 8 and Mockito 2.7.5

Comment: it's showing mismatch in arguments while compiling itself

Comment: @MahenderReddyYasa I'm afraid that's not enough information to diagnose; this may be related, or it may be something else. Please ask a separate question, including your code and the full text of your error, and link to this question so answerers will have the context.

Answer (score 5):

You can match a generic `Class<T>` argument using simply `any( Class.class )`, eg.:

```
Mockito.when( mongoUtil.documentToPojo( Mockito.any( Document.class ),
                                        Mockito.any( Class.class ) ) );
```

Cheers,

Comment: Mockito.any didnt work for T and I have mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using ArgumentMatchers.any() qualified with the type, like so:

```
Mockito.when(
    mongoUtil.documentToPojo(
        Mockito.any(Document.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.<Class<WorkItemDTO>>any()
    )
).thenReturn(...);
```